# How to push a UIViewController from a modal UIView?

Tags: uiview, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I have a modal UIView created like below but I am unable to find a way to push another UIViewController from the UIView. The view's parent UIViewController does have a UINavigationController. All the code attempts  below fail. The UIView has a UICollectionView

parent UIViewController

```
let searchView = SearchView()

view.addSubview(searchView)
```

modal UIView

```
class SearchView: UIView,
              UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,
              UICollectionViewDataSource {

var collectionView: UICollectionView!


 ----


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let myViewController: MyViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “MyViewController") as! MyViewController

//      let currentController = self.getCurrentViewController()

//        currentController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)

// self.parentViewController.navigationController.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true) 


    let vc = self.window?.rootViewController

    let navController = vc?.navigationController

    navController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one instance property of type `UIViewController` with your `SearchView`. Now use this property to `pushViewController`. After that initialized it where you are creating instance of `SearchView`.

```
class SearchView: UIView,
          UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,
          UICollectionViewDataSource {

     var collectionView: UICollectionView!
     var vc: UIViewController?


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let myViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController
        vc?.navigationController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)

    }
```

Now where you are adding this `SearchView` as subview set the vc property of its to `self`.

```
let searchView = SearchView()
searchView.vc = self
view.addSubview(searchView)
```